# Change unofficial date format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, format

I have to change the format of my date variable form:

```
var dateTime= "28 Februar 2013 - 09:50";
```

to this:

```
var dateTime = "2013-02-28 09:50:00";
```

How can this be done? I know how to do it for normal, supported datetime formats, but not for this specific one.

Comment: [The `Date` API has all the tools you need.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: You might want to look into moment.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/BnQ9L/)  : Solution using jQuery:

You need first to `parse` your String variable to `date object` and then `format` it using `formatDate`:

```
var dateTime= "28 February 2013 - 09:50";
var time=dateTime.split("- ");
var date= $.datepicker.parseDate("dd MM yy", dateTime);

var output=$.datepicker.formatDate('dd mm yy',date)+' '+time[1]+':00'
$('#date1').text(output);
```